# What's the difference between firebase/auth/react-native and firebase/auth?

Tags: firebase, react-native, firebase-authentication, expo

They seem to be the same but I can't find any documentation on what the core differences are. There's only documentation for `firebase/auth` and it seems to be also applicable for `firebase/auth/react-native` so I've been following that. I just found out about `/react-native` from somewhere along learning how to use auth.

I'm pretty sure I should use `/react-native` for whatever reason but would like to understand more. Does anyone have links or explanation for this?

Seems like other packages like `firebase/app` doesn't have `/react-native` dir

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The key distinction is the target platform: firebase/auth/react-native is specifically designed for React Native apps, whereas firebase/auth is intended for web applications.